# Linux find catalogs and print only names

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

i wanna search for the catalogs which have the "program" in their names and echo these names in console. I have wrote this, but isn't working:

find usr -type d -name "program" -exec echo {}
The error is find: missing argument to `-exec'.

find usr -type d -name "program"
usr/lib64/libreofice/program

How to fix my command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tiny example with the `*` wildcard.

```
find /my/path -name "*program*"
```

If you don' use wildcards, it will try to find exactly the files named `program`. Also, echoing is done automatically, you don't need the `exec` command.

**Update**
Answering to your comment. You can get the base name (name without the path) with:

```
find . -name "*program*" -exec basename {} \;
```

Comment: But it's returning name with the whole path: xxx/ccc/program
 I just wanna the names of catalogs (not files).